# How do I get the last Energy Sphere in Level 1-2

Tags: kirby-return-to-dreamland

In World 1-2, after you defeat the boss that looks like a green knight, you can see the last Energy Sphere of the level sitting on a platform that also has a Waddle Dee on it. Normally, Kirby can cut the ropes of these platforms causing them to fall - however, in this case, there is a wall in the way.

I tried to just suck the Sphere off of the platform - I succeeded in sucking up the Waddle Dee, but no Sphere.  I also tried using the Copy Abilities available to me (Beam and the one where you shoot flames) with no luck.

How do I get that last Sphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to have the sword (or other cutting weapon).  Fortunately the boss you had just defeated has the sword ability.

The energy sphere should be sitting in a small enclosed area where there is a solid platform held by a rope blocking your path (and the Waddle Dee).  On the outside, there should be a smaller platform.  To get to the energy sphere, you need to cut the rope to drop the platform to give you access to it.

To get to it, just stand on the outside platform facing the rope and slice with your sword.  The range of the sword swing should be able to hit the rope.  Other cutting abilities (e.g., cutter, ninja, etc.) may or may not work as they don't have the range or would be able to go through the wall.  But getting the sword would be easier since you had just defeated a boss that had it.

Here's a hint, about 95% of the time you fight a mini-boss in a level, you'll need its power to get an energy sphere that comes up right after.  So you should *always* take the power of the boss if you want to collect all the spheres, even if you don't want its ability and you already have your favorite weapon.  You'll almost always need it.  Besides, getting back your favorite abilities should be easy anyway in other levels or the ability rooms you unlock.

Comment: In many scenarios, another strategy if you don't want to lose your previous ability, grab the star after eating the miniboss - holding it resets the "vanish" timer while also letting you carry the ability straight to where you needed the boss's ability. Then, once you're finished (since it's largely one-shot), you can toss it, drop the boss ability, and get back the original one.